# Performatic and "correct" way to search string within an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I looking for a very fast array search workaround.

What I really need: check a array of emails against a blacklist as a csv string.

My solutions, for each email:

1. Use `blacklist.indexOf(email) >= 0` - very slow. I tried

   `"email1@gmail.com;email2@gmail.com ..."`
2. split blacklist into an array and use `array.IndexOf(email) >= 0` - much more faster

   `["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com" ...]`
3. Create an object with where each property is an email from blacklist and assigned to "true" and do `myObject[email]`; This seems to be way more faster but it looks very much like a "kludge" .

   `{"email1@gmail.com":true,"email2@gmail.com":true ...}`

How can I make this search fast and to be not a "kludge" ?

PS the problem is not the size of the blacklist, The black list has near 1k emails. However we must check 400k emails against it every time.

Comment: You can also use Map or Set to store blackmail

Comment: How large is your CSV file? A large file would definitely take much time.

Comment: If by "email" you mean "email **address**", your third solution isn't a kludge. It's a common way to address this problem, but offloading the job of matching the email address string to a property name to the implementation of the object in your JavaScript engine. JS engines optimize objects **aggressively**, so that's likely to be your best approach. (And in fact, is almost certainly an answer to a duplicate here somewhere...)

Comment: Do you really have the *whole* email body blacklisted? That's weird.

Comment: If you have sorted emails, you can perform binary search. It also means you probably don't need to load the entire CSV into memory if it's fast enough to open the file and move a cursor to required lines skipping the search space you don't care about.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder A `Set` might be more appropriate though

Comment: But otherwise, I agree with the notion that number 3 is not a kludge. It seems a normal caching technique, so you don't have to scan the CSV each time.

Comment: @Bergi - Very possibly.

Comment: I answered all comments in the question.

Comment: If you don't want to do a fast operation your going to have to deal with using `indexOf`. The 3rd approach is the most performant way to do this by a large margin and is the correct approach. Any time you happen to have a list of unique keys and need to iterate it though several times to find some key, you probably should be making it into a hashmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, it is better to go with a prefilled `Map`. 
You can split your csv string and iterate over it.
I've written two performance tests and ran them in Chrome. With the help of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure.

I created two Maps. An email Map with 400k entries and a blacklist Map with 1k entries. 
Downside: The initialisation takes a long time.

```
// noprotect
console.clear();

const EMAIL_COUNT = 400000;
const BLACKLIST_EMAIL_COUNT = 1000;
let mailMatches = 0;

// arrays
const emails = new Map();
const blacklist = new Map();

// 1k blacklisted mails
for (let bl = 0; bl < BLACKLIST_EMAIL_COUNT; bl++) {
    if (bl % 2 === 0) {
        blacklist.set('email' + bl, 'email' + bl);
    } else {
        blacklist.set('email@' + bl, 'email@' + bl);
    }
}

// 400k mails
for (let j = 0; j < EMAIL_COUNT; j++) {
    emails.set('email' + j, 'email' + j);
}

performance.mark('perfMailList-start');

// 1ms (includes, emails, reverse)
blacklist.forEach(blacklistItem => {
    if (emails.has(blacklistItem)) {
        mailMatches++;
    }
});

// 32ms
/*emails.forEach(email => {
    if(blacklist.has(email)) {
        mailMatches++;
    }
})*/

performance.mark('perfMailList-end');

performance.measure('perfMailList', 'perfMailList-start', 'perfMailList-end');

const measures = performance.getEntriesByName('perfMailList');
const measure = measures[0];

console.log(`${measure.duration}ms and ${mailMatches} found blacklisted mails`);

// Clean up the stored markers.
performance.clearMarks();
performance.clearMeasures();
```

And some loops (for, for reverse, forEach) with alternately `includes` or `indexOf`.

```
// noprotect
console.clear();

const EMAIL_COUNT = 400000;
const BLACKLIST_EMAIL_COUNT = 1000;
let mailMatches = 0;

// arrays
const emails = [];
const blacklist = [];

// 1k blacklisted mails
for (let bl = 0; bl < BLACKLIST_EMAIL_COUNT; bl++) {
    // console.log(i)
    if (bl % 2 === 0) {
        blacklist.push('email' + bl);
    } else {
        blacklist.push('email@' + bl);
    }
}

// 400k mails
for (let j = 0; j < EMAIL_COUNT; j++) {
    emails.push('email' + j);
}

performance.mark('perfMailList-start');

// 524ms (indexOf, emails)
/*emails.forEach(mail => {
if(blacklist.indexOf(mail) >= 0){
        mailMatches++;
}
})*/

// 583ms (includes, blacklist)
/*blacklist.forEach(blacklistItem => {
if(emails.indexOf(blacklistItem) >= 0){
        mailMatches++;
}
})*/

// --------------------------

// 521ms (includes, emails)
/*emails.forEach(mail => {
if(blacklist.includes(mail)){
        mailMatches++;
}
})*/

// 600ms (includes, blacklist)
/*blacklist.forEach(blacklistItem => {
if(emails.includes(blacklistItem)){
        mailMatches++;
}
})*/

// --------------------------

// 638ms (includes, emails, reverse)
/*for(var i = BLACKLIST_EMAIL_COUNT; i--;) {
    if(emails.includes(blacklist[i])){
        mailMatches++;
    }
}*/

// 632ms (indexOf, emails, reverse)
/*for(var i = BLACKLIST_EMAIL_COUNT; i--;) {
    if(emails.indexOf(blacklist[i]) >= 0){
        mailMatches++;
    }
}*/

// --------------------------

// 530ms (includes, emails)
/*for(var i = EMAIL_COUNT; i--;) {
    if(blacklist.includes(emails[i])){
        mailMatches++;
    }
    }*/

// 530ms (indexOf, emails)
/*for(var i = EMAIL_COUNT; i--;) {
    if(blacklist.indexOf(emails[i]) >= 0){
        mailMatches++;
    }
}*/

// --------------------------

// 525ms (includes, emails)
/*for(let i = 0; i < EMAIL_COUNT; i++) {
    if(blacklist.includes(emails[i])) {
        mailMatches++;
    }
}*/

// 540ms (indexOf, emails)
/*for(let i = 0; i < EMAIL_COUNT; i++) {
    if(blacklist.indexOf(emails[i]) >= 0) {
        mailMatches++;
    }
    }*/

// --------------------------

// 668ms (includes, blacklist)
/*for(let i = 0; i < BLACKLIST_EMAIL_COUNT; i++) {
    if(emails.includes(blacklist[i])) {
        mailMatches++;
    }
}*/

// 687ms (indexOf, blacklist)
/*for(let k = 0; k < BLACKLIST_EMAIL_COUNT; k++) {
    if(emails.indexOf(blacklist[k]) >= 0) {
        mailMatches++;
    }
}*/

// --------------------------

// 1367ms (equals)
/*for(let i = 0; i < EMAIL_COUNT; i++) {
    for(let k = 0; k < BLACKLIST_EMAIL_COUNT; k++) {
        if(emails[i] === blacklist[k]) {
        mailMatches++;
        }
    }
}*/

performance.mark('perfMailList-end');

performance.measure('perfMailList', 'perfMailList-start', 'perfMailList-end');

const measures = performance.getEntriesByName('perfMailList');
const measure = measures[0];

console.log(`${measure.duration}ms and ${mailMatches} found blacklisted mails`);

// Clean up the stored markers.
performance.clearMarks();
performance.clearMeasures();
```

---

**MacBook:** Pro (15-inch, 2016)

**Processor:** 2,9 GHz Intel Core i7

**Memory:** 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3

Answer (score -1):

use `Array#includes` and let engine implementers worry about optimization

```
blacklist.includes(email)
```

Alternatively, use Sets or Maps

https://jsperf.com/array-includes-and-find-methods-vs-set-has

Comment: That will be almost exactly the same speed as the OP's `indexOf` solution, so if they're not happy with `indexOf`, they're not going to be happy with `includes`.

Comment: Wouldn't that behave the same way as `blacklist.indexOf` in terms of performance?

Comment: well, it's going to have to search through the array in any event.

you could convert the array to an object or a map and use it as a lookup table

```
const blackTable = blacklist.reduce((a, k) => ({...a, [k]: true}), {})
blackTable[email] // true or undefined
```

Comment: If performance is hampered by having a HUGE blacklist csv file, this kind of tweak won’t solve the problem. Perhaps offloading the check to a server or a worker is a better idea?